# DropdownMenu on alertdialog in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, android-alertdialog, scrollable, selectlist

Sometime a picture is better than a lot of word. So i would like to do something like this.
I have no idee it seems to me that is 3 DropdowMenu in a alertdialog but i'm not sure.
Thanks in advance. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is IOS-style picker. You can use 3 CupertinoPicker to obtain the above UI.

Ref: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html